# Processes during stress test get killed

Tags: kill-process, stress

I've run into a somewhat curious situation.

I'm currently stress testing a couple of new machines running Fedora 20. I've tried `mprime`, `memtester` and `systester`.

All execute for a while and suddenly end with nothing besides a "Killed" message. Nothing in the kernel about it needing to kill processes or anything else relating to it. The tools themselves also do not report any errors.

I have custom limits set for users, but the processes in question are run by root, so it should not be interfering.

SELinux is disabled.

Exampe output:

```
 Calculating 134217728 digits of pi
 -----------------------------------------
 Turn:   2  Errors:   0       Threads:   4
 Running For:  0h 26m 19.248s  ChkErr:   0
 Failed After:  No fail yet
 -----------------------------------------
 Loop Digits State    Time
 ---------------------------------
    0      1  OK   0h 27m 17.397s
    1      2  OK   0h 28m  0.195s
    2      4  OK   0h 28m 56.899s
    3      8  OK   0h 29m 53.599s
    4     16  OK   0h 30m 49.982s
    5     32  OK   0h 31m 45.570s
    6     64  OK   0h 32m 41.529s
    7    128  OK   0h 33m 38.750s
    8    256  OK   0h 34m 35.061s
    9    512  OK   0h 35m 30.452s
   10     1K  OK   0h 36m 26.453s
   11     2K  OK   0h 37m 22.729s
   12     4K  OK   0h 38m 18.829s
   13     8K  OK   0h 39m 16.309s
   14    16K  OK   0h 40m 12.570s
   15    32K  OK   0h 41m  8.053s
   16    64K  OK   0h 42m  4.501s
   17   128K  OK   0h 43m  0.002s
   18   256K  OK   0h 43m 56.505s
   19   512K  OK   0h 44m 52.981s
   20     1M  OK   0h 45m 49.986s
Killed
```

Comment: Any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: Are you certain it's the system killing these stress test tools and not the tools themselves?

Comment: I've added an example. There is nothing in the logs, I've checked `/porc/kmesg` as well as the journal.

Answer (score 0):

Error was on my part, I changed the limits and didn't restart the sessions running the jobs, so the old limits were still in place.